# No response when paying using Solid Trust Pay account balance

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am integrating the Solid Trust Pay payment gateway. My button is:

```
<form action="https://solidtrustpay.com/handle.php" method="post" name="form" id="form">
<input type='hidden' name="inf_token"  id="inf_token" value="f6f7369316c4928fdceaaed397356f5b"/>
<input type=hidden name='merchantAccount' value='<merchantAccount>' />
<input type='hidden' name='sci_name' value='Pay using STP' />
<input type='hidden' name="amount" value="1" readonly/><br />
<input type='hidden' name="currency" value="USD" />
<input type='hidden' name="testmode" value="ON" />
<input type='hidden' name="item_id" value="8787878" />
<input type='hidden' name="cat_id" value="7" />
<input type='hidden' name="notify_url" value="{my_base_url}/register/stp_payment_notify" />
<input type='hidden' name="confirm_url" value="{my_base_url}/register/stp_payment_success" />
<input type='hidden' name="return_url" value="{my_base_url}/register/stp_payment_return" />
<input type='hidden' name="cancel_url" value="{my_base_url}/register/user_register" />
</form>
```

I can get a response while paying using credit card, but paying using STP account balance didn't return any response. How can I get a response?

Comment: you should ask solidtrustpay

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code does not belong to any specific SolidTrust Pay account, as the "merchantAccount" field should be the username, not just "merchantAccount" again.  Additionally, there is not a proper sci_name; this has to be created inside the SolidTrust Pay account in the MERCHANT ZONE area and is very specific.  And finally, your cancel_URL also looks incorrect as what you are showing as your cancel URL references a "user register", but a cancel_URL is what a customer is directed to if they abandon the payment.

For more direct assistance, visit the SolidTrust Pay HELP CENTRE at:  support.solidtrustpay.com